# ASP.net MVC one controller two different strongly typed VIews

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I want smth. like this. When user types mydomain.com/Message/  he gets all his message threads, but when he types mydomain.com/Message/John he gets message thread between him and john. I Don't know how to implement view for this here is controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index(String userName)
    {
        var user = UserRepository.GetUserByDisplayName(userName);


        if (user == null || user.UserId.Equals(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId))
        {
            IQueryable<MessageThread> messageThreads =
            MessageThreadRepository.GetMessageThreadsForUser(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
            return View(messageThreads);
        }

        MessageThread thread = MessageThreadRepository.GetThreadBetweenUsers(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, userName);
        return View(thread);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check View method's overloads http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310(v=vs.98).aspx

Create views for all cases and pass viewName as parameter to View("viewName", yourObject)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what or how is your methods but I hope it will help you..

Your url like this http://mydomain.com/Message?userName=John

```
    private DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(String userName)
    {
        IEnumerable<Message> messages = db.Messages;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
        {
            messages = messages.Where(x => x.UserName == userName);
        }
        return View(messages);
    }
```

But don't forget to use ViewModel..